# Unbinding Jquery Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding an event to two ID's at once.  After the fact, is there a way to target one ID to unbind the event?

Below is a simplified version of my code.  One event is unbound/bound after an AJAX request returns an HTML template... if template 'AA' renders, the first event is bound; if template 'BB' renders, the second script is bound.

```
//Template AA
$('#container').off('dblclick', '#store, #compare_store');
$('#container').on('dblclick', '#store, #compare_store', function(){
     console.dir('test1');
});

//Template BB
$('#container').off('dblclick', '#store');   //This does not unbind the event listed as above
$('#container').on('dblclick', '#store', function(){
     console.dir('test2');
});

/* Console Output When double-clicking '#store':
   test1
   test2
*/
```

When double clicking on the '#store' element, both events are currently triggered.  The desired effect is to have the second event unbind the first event (for '#store' only), and bind a new event.

I am aware that binding each ID separately would provide the desired results.  I'm also aware that using a class would also do the job.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the `off` function work if you unbind for the original selector `#store, #compare_store`? I know that's not what you want but I'm curious if that's what jquery expects for this to work. I honestly don't know how jquery would handle that, you may need to bind the event separately

Comment: You really can't do it like that, as you have to pass in the exact same selector to `off()` that was used to bind the event in `on()`. you could namespace the event, but that wouldn't help either as you still can't remove half an event handler, it's all or nothing when you remove event handlers like that.

Comment: @ helion3: When using off with "#store, #compare_store" it works because it is verbatim.

Comment: @adeneo: that's what I feared.  All my trouble shooting lead me to believe exactly what you stated... I was just hoping there was a way to keep my code consolidated.  I'll likely end up naming the event function.  At least this will keep each binding to a one liner, and avoid some redundant code.

Comment: @ejc sounds like a personal problem; C IN; C OUT;

Answer (score 0):

Chang the selectors so that the `off` method call matches the `on` selector:

```
//Template AA
$('#container').on('click', '#compare_store', function(){
     console.log("a", this);
}).on('click', '#store', function(){
     console.log("b", this);
});

//Template BB
$('#container').off('click', '#store');   //This does not unbind the event listed as above
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzgnH/